# Google ads display error 404. Is there a hidden redirect script?

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, adsense

Google adsense on a Wordpress blog shows error 404. Lets call this blog, website1.com. So far, I have done the following:

1. backed up mysql database
2. terminated the cPaneL account
3. created a new cPaneL account
4. installed a new Wordpress again
5. dropped all tables in mysql database and installed the old database.
6. installed a new Wordpress theme
7. put the google adsense code manually

But the Google ads still dont show. I checked the access logs and it showed the following:

```
"GET /google_adsense_script.html HTTP/1.1" 404 5569 "http://www.website1.com/featured/a-peek-of-banaue-rice-terraces-in-ifugao/"
"GET /wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/background.png HTTP/1.1" 404 5574 "http://www.website1.com/google_adsense_script.html" "
"GET /google_adsense_script.html HTTP/1.1" 404 5589 "http://www.website1.com/awards-and-recognitions/chuva-post-chuva-chu/"
"GET /poloralphlauren/?france=basket+ralph+lauren+pas+cher HTTP/1.0" 503 521 "http://www.website1.com/"
"GET /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 33285 "http://www.website1.com/poloralphlauren/?france=basket+ralph+lauren+pas+cher"
```

Are those redirect urls? I always see "google_adsense_script.html" and "poloralphlauren". The website doesn't have files like that but they keep showing up in the logs.

I tried using the same Wordpress theme and same Google adsense script on another Wordpress blog, website2.com, everything works fine. I got no problems.

To summarize: website1.com and website2.com both use the same Wordpress theme and same google adsense codes. But google adsense on website1.com shows error 404.

Is it possible that there is a hidden redirect script that can cause google adsense on the website to go error 404? If there is, how do I look for them?

**update as of 1/27/2016**

I scanned the two Wordpress websites (website1.com and website2.com) using Quttera to find out if they are clean. I found 5 hidden iframes on website1.com:

```
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/about\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/contact-us\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/privacy-policy\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/sitemap\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/links\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
```

I have no idea where these iframes are coming from. They contain scripts?

Comment: looks like your wp installation was infected at some point. so its probably a good thing they 404. Google adsense does not work separately as `google_adsense_script.html` it works by using js in your pages (usually), and seeing as you have no idea what `polo ralph lauren` is doing, I can almost guarantee that you have/had some malware. New wordpress installation may have helped clean things up. Please be aware.

Comment: I scanned the two Wordpress websites (website1.com and website2.com) using Quttera to find out if they are clean. I found 5 hidden iframes on website1.com.

I have no idea where these iframes are coming from. They contain scripts?

Comment: you dont need quterra. you need to go through your wordpress files (inc wp-admin/wp-content/wp-includes, etc) and locate google_adsense_script.html. Check your htaccess file to ensure it is clean. Do a search for poloralphlauren in all of the files on the system to try figure out the location of these. Chances are they are just infected plugins, so it might be worth deleting and reinstalling plugins.

Comment: @mani thank you, but i have already done that. I dont use quterra anymore, I use Chrome developer tools instead. Using that I can see `google_adsense_script.html` is being loaded on every page where Google ads return error 404. I searched the HTML codes, php files, searched in the VPS using `grep -ir`, i cant find them. Even if I disabled all the plugins, the hidden script is still there.

Comment: right. did a bit of digging around. google_adsense_script.html is indeed for "alternative" ads by adsense. do you have an ad blocker installed in your browser? also, you should run grep for poloralphlauren..

Comment: @mani, you were right about the google alternative ads! thank you very much! my only problem now is poloralphlauren