# How do I remove a hidden iframe I did not create?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I scanned 2 Wordpress websites using Quttera to find out if they are clean. Lets call these blogs website1.com and website2.com respectively. I found 5 hidden iframes on website1.com:

```
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/about\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/contact-us\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/privacy-policy\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/sitemap\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
iframe sandbox=\"allow-scripts\" security=\"restricted\" src=\"http:\/\/www.website1.com\/links\/embed\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" title=\"Embedded WordPress Post\" frameborder=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" class=\"wp-embedded-content\"
```

Both website1.com and website2.com use the same Wordpress theme. So I dont really get it where these iframes are coming from.

Comment: If those were “malicious” iframes inserted by a hacker, then they would likely load content from external domains, but not your own. Plus, the class `wp-embedded-content` rather suggests that this comes from within your system. Are you sure that is not the fault of some plugin, that inserts those for whatever reason?

Comment: im sure it doesnt come from a plugin. both website1.com and website2.com have the same plugins and wordpress themes but I only got problems on website1.com

Here's the history, by the way. No one's answering my question there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006583/google-ads-display-error-404-is-there-a-hidden-redirect-script

Comment: @CBroe I noticed that these iframes look like they are coming from the website pages (e.g. About, Contact Us, Privacy Policy, Sitemap, Links). So I tried disabling the pages (made them private). Then suddenly, the hidden iframes dont load anymore and the Google ads appear now - in the homepage at least. Thank goodness.

What I cant understand is how the content of the pages are loaded in the homepage using iframes?

My problem now are the individual posts of the website. Im assuming there are still hidden iframes loaded in every post because the original problem still exists.